# java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data. for select query

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-connector

While running the SQL executeQuery function with select command in java even though it's a select query I still get the SQLException saying

```
ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.
```

This issue happens only during high load. Otherwise the query works quite well.

I am using mysql connector 8.0.16

Only restart of the server is helping here, but need to handle this in the code as well to keep it safe.

This is the sample function

```
public CacheKey getResult(String type, String colId) {
ResultSet resultSet = null;
PreparedStatement statement = null;
try {
    
      String request = "select * from Table where a = ?";
      //mCxnContainer is connection which is declared at class level
      statement = mCxnContainer.getStatement(request);
      if (statement == null) {
           mCxnContainer = getNewConnection();
           statement = mCxnContainer.getStatement(request);
      }
      statement.setString(1, colId);
      resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
      returnEntry = cacheEntry.toEntry(resultSet);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStacktrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (resultSet != null)
            resultSet.close();
            if (statement != null)
            statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
    }
    return returnEntry;
}
```

Comment: Which language, how does your code looks like?

Comment: I Think result set is not refreshed or the transaction is not handled properly.

Comment: It's java code, I've added the sample code snippet

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because of the connection.
Once we started closing the connection and getting the new connection from pool as in when needed, the issue got solved.